# Keep getting "cannot read property style of null" error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on my own website and not good with codes yet. When I am scrolling down I want to appear another content of the navbar and when I am on the top, original navbar is appearing. I want this to be done in pure JavaScript with no libraries or framewokrs. Please see codes below and I know that codes are not organised. I will do that later on.

```
    var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
var appear = document.querySelector(".appear")

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(document.body.scrollTop > 70){
        hide.style.display = "block";
        appear.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        hide.style.display = "none";
        appear.style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

```
    nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3FA9A5;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.hide{
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Long Cang', cursive;
    display: block;
}
.appear{
    height: 70px;
    display: none;
}

.appear img{
    width: 210px;

}

ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;

}


.text{
    text-align: center;
}


.profile {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;

}

#main{
    width: 100%;
}

.post{
    margin-left: 4.165%;
}

#image{
    width: 100%;
}

#post-divide{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.comments{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 68.5px;
    padding-bottom: 293.5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
 h2{
    text-align: center;
 }

 .center{
    grid-column: 2;
 }
```

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Long+Cang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">Unknown</li>
        <li class="appear"><img src="cat.png"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="profile text">
                <img id="main" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/86629641/superthumb.jpg?t=1384568664">
                <hr>
                <p>12 posts</p>
                <p>instagram</p>
                <button>Subscribe!</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <div>
                    <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
                </div>
                <hr id="post-divide">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="comments text"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1 center">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <div>
                    <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
                </div>
                <hr id="post-divide">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="comments text"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I think I should add something to the JS code but don't know why
Would be thankful if you would advise me how could I write HTML/CSS code so I do not have to create 2 navbars if it is possible

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Please provide proper selector.

`document.querySelector(".hide");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
var appear = document.querySelector(".appear")
```

So you should use class selector

Answer (score 2):

The following instruction:

```
document.querySelector("hide");
```

Will query for elements like:

```
<hide></hide>
```

Since plain selectors without prefix (`div`, `header`, `span`) will query for the whole element tags, not for classes or attrbitues.

Maybe you meant to query for the class, using the `.`:

```
document.querySelector(".hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "hide" and "appear" as selectors but they do not exist in your HTML.

Use ".hide" and ".appear" in your querySelector instead.

```
 var hide = document.querySelector(".hide"); 
 var appear = document.querySelector(".appear");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both navbars have a static data, I would suggest to keep both of them and follow with answers of guys, that suggested to update querySelector param. Or you can hide/show the data inside of navbar (in your case it's only `ul` element) and leave the whole navbar always visible. So you can put classes appear/hide on `ul` element instea of `navbar` and then in JS get them with `document.querySelector('.navbar .hide')` and `document.querySelector('.navbar .appear')`.

Using framework/library will definitely simplify it. 
However, if you still want to have only one navbar in pure js/html/css (or it's data just dynamic) I would probably do like this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="cat.png"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

somewhere in JS:

```
var navbarUl = document.querySelector('.navbar ul');
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 70) {
    navbarUl.innerHtml = '';
    navbarUl.appendChild(getTopNavbarHTML);
  } else {
    navbarUl.innerHtml = '';
    navbarUl.appendChild(getNavbarHTML);
  }
}
```

getNavbarHTML and getTopNavbarHTML - will return `documentFragment` with `li` elements, see for details https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createdocumentfragment.asp

But changing DOM during a scroll event can drastically decrease performance of a web app